# Type Error '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, math

I am getting a type error from the following code:

```
import random


def f(x):
    return x**2


def Sample(npts):
    sample = []

# Generate random numbers from 0 to 10.
randomlist = []
for _ in range(npts):  # just counting from 0 to npts-1
    r = random.random() # random.random() generates numbers from 0 to 1, including 0.2 etc.
    r *= 10  # convert to 0 to 10 range
    assert r >= 0 and r <= 10, "random number r should be in [0, 10]"  # verify that r is in [0, 10]
    randomlist.append(r)  # save to a list

# Save result of function f
for v in randomlist: # get each item in the list
    y = f(v)
    sample.append(y)

return sample


# start
npts = 100
result = Sample(npts)
print(f'result length: {len(result)}')
print(f'result: {result}')
```

I presume this is because I am trying to check between an int and a list. I am given to understand you can use numpy to compute it as intended, however, I don't quite understand, so if someone could explain to me I'd be quite grateful.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. Please format your code properly.

Comment: Sorry thats on me forgetting to indent after pasting onto here

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually recreate your initial TypeError given the code sample provided. That being said, your code can be simplified quite a bit - there's no need to `assert` the value of `r`, or multiply relatively. How about this:

```
import random

def compute_sample(npts):
    return [ random.uniform(0.0, 10.0)**2 for _ in range(npts) ]

# start
result = compute_sample(100)
print(f'result length: {len(result)}')
print(f'result: {result}')
```

Comment: Sorry I think you've misunderstood, it's on me for not indenting. Both the for _ in range and the for v in randomlist are a part of def Sample

Comment: In that case, please edit your original post with the exact indentation so we can re-create the error. In addition, please provide the compiler error message too. Even so, currently there's only 1 place in the code where `>=` is evaluated, and that's comparing `r` to a number.